# [Tkinter]Binding Keyboard Keys to a Radiobutton

Tags: python, button, tkinter, bind

I am trying to bind `F1`key to my radiobutton in my tkinter GUI.
I tried this

```
import tkinter as tk

def stack():
   print('StackOverflow')

root = tk.Tk()

v = tk.IntVar()

RadBut = tk.Radiobutton(root, text = 'Check', variable = v, value = 1, command = stack)
RadBut.pack() 

RadBut.bind_all("<F1>", stack)

root.mainloop()
```

If I run this and try to press f1 it gives out

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: stack() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

But clicking on the button with mouse works fine.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The callback function of `bind` will receive the event object as argument.  So add an argument to `stack()`: `def stack(event=None)`, then it can be used by both the `bind` and `command`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @acw1668 said, you need to give an argument to the `stack()` function.

I would like to add that it doesn't have to be a `None`.

Here is your code:

```py
from tkinter import *

def stack(event = "<F1>"):
   print('StackOverflow')

root = Tk()

v = IntVar()

RadBut = Radiobutton(root, text = 'Check', variable = v, value = 1, command = stack)
RadBut.pack() 

RadBut.bind_all("<F1>", stack)

root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey @BluNyte, would you mind upvoting my answer? I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: sure mate thank you for the help